# PMOS + resistor \$I_{DS} - V_{DS}\$ curve

Tags: mosfet, pmos, iv-curve

I'm trying to plot the \$I_{DS} - V_{DS}\$ graph for a PMOS and a resistor.

I'm getting this so far:

[image]

Weird thing is, what I should get (based on my course) should be something like :
[image]

How come the curves aren't converging to a single point in my case? And what are those odd curves on the left side?

Anything I've done wrong in my simulation ?